# How do I make the colors in matpoltlib appear less vague? python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot data in python using matplotlib, but the colors are very faded in the plot, I've tried several "rainbow, Paired, spectral_r" which seem to have a "strong" color but they all appear vague on the plot. It is for a specific task so it is important to be able to easily difference the colors. Any Ideas as to why? Thanks!

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
group = ("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
plt.scatter(z[:,0],z[:,1], c = yeastLabel, edgecolor='none', alpha=0.5,
            cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('rainbow'))
cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.set_label("elevation (m)", labelpad=-1)
plt.xlabel('PC1')
plt.ylabel('PC2')
plt.title('Matplot scatter plot')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Oh, sorry! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The alpha argument in [`plt.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html) essentially sets the transparency for the markers, with 0 being transparent and 1 being opaque. So, for your code you would simply set the alpha value to 1.

For example:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y = [i**2 for i in x]

ax1.scatter(x, y, s=20, alpha=0.5)
ax1.set_title("Alpha value of 0.5")

ax2.scatter(x, y, s=20, alpha=1)
ax2.set_title("Alpha value of 1")

plt.show()
```

[image]